# Typescript Unions Types with generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm working with typescript and unable to figure out how to make this function generic with the constraints.

This is a very contrived example but shows a gist of what I'm trying to accomplish.
**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zfsvjh)**

```
interface Customer {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface User {
  username: string;
  role: string;
}

function getData<T extends User | Customer>(payload: User): T {
  if (payload.role === 'xyz') {
    // make ajax call
     
    return { username: '', role: 'xyz' };
  } else {
    // make ajax call
    return { name: 'soemdata', age: 109 };
  }
}


const user = getData<User>({ username: 'test', role: 'xyz' });

const customer = getData<Customer>({ username: 'test', role: 'xyza' });
```

getData returns error
`Type '{ username: string; role: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'. '{ username: string; role: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Customer | User'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th reason that you cannot write that code is; `T` is extension of `User` or `Customer` but the type `T` could contain more properties of its own. The type of `T` is actually vague and you wouldn't know it. You can only return `T` here and you dont know what `T` is specifically.

So, for that reason you cannot return some specific types such as `{ name: string; age: number; }` and `{ username: string; role: string; }`. And this is how generic extension works in most languages.

You can ofcourse force the return type to be `T` which is always true in this case and wont fail, So code below would work fine,

```
function getData<T extends User | Customer>(payload: User): T {
  if (payload.role === 'xyz') {
    return { username: '', role: 'xyz' } as T;
  } else {
    return { name: 'soemdata', age: 109 } as T;
  }
}
```

The best way you can deal with this is using `Union` type instead of generics.

```
function getData(payload: User): (User | Customer) {
  if (payload.role === 'xyz') {
    return { username: '', role: 'xyz' };
  } else {
    // make ajax call
    return { name: 'soemdata', age: 109 };
  }
}
```

If you had any `T` argument passed to your function, you could then know `T` and return `T`, but you dont have reference to `T` anywhere and you are trying to return that unknown specific / generic type, which is only extension of `User` or `Customer` but is not a `User` or `Customer`.